# Update Mac Mini server without keyboard from Windows laptop

Tags: laptop, mac-mini, screen-sharing

I recently bought a Mac Mini (3,1) server to use Xcode. I have a Dell laptop, an extra monitor, a USB mouse, but no spare keyboard besides the one in my laptop.

The Mac Mini came with OS X 10.6.8, and I would like to upgrade that to 10.8 (free upgrade from the Mac website), but I'm concerned about my lack of keyboard for configuration.

I understand there are some screen sharing options that I could use to access my Mini server from my PC laptop, but I don't really know how this is done.

Could I feasibly do this all from my PC laptop using screen sharing? And how?

Comment: Buy or borrow a keyboard for the upgrade.  Sure, it might be possible to remotely upgrade, but if something breaks networking then you be stuck.  A cheap USB keyboard can be had for $5-10 if you look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using the free version of [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/) as well as upgrading to OS X 10.9 (Maverick) which is available (also for free) from the Apple App store. I use LogMeIn to remotely administer a family member's iMac in another part of town from my own Windows box at home and recently upgraded the iMac from 10.6.8 to 10.9 for them. It was a huge download (5.3 GB), but in all other respects the upgrade process went very smoothly and the vast majority of installed applications continued to work just fine afterwards.